# Laravel artisan migrate not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Im using vagrant multiple sites and i install Laravel to my second website.
I tried to migrate tables and my database certainly empty but im getting this error

```
 [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "users" already exists
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "users" already exists
```

I tried php artisan refresh reset etc...

Comment: How is your database called in .env, and what folder are you in on the command line when you run php artisan migrate?

Comment: im on to root and my env file is default

Comment: im using vagrant and i create two database in homestead.yaml its my second database and im successfully enter this database its empty

Comment: When you say your env file is default.. are you just using a sqlite db, which exists in your storage directory as database.sqlite (laravel defaults) with .env variables "DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret"?

Comment: More importantly, does your 'config/database.php' match what you have set in your .env file, and does that match the database you set up in homestead.yaml?

Comment: Thank you DonnaJo i dont understand why but in my env file DB_CONNECTION=sqlite i see this and i delete now its working.

Comment: No problem @Talip Durmus. Just for future reference, your database configuration is set in the 'config/database.php' file. By default, it calls 'DB_CONNECTION' from your .env file. So, whatever you have set there is what your php artisan database-related commands will be connected to. I believe there is a default 'mysql' fallback for the database connection in 'config/database.php' as well. So, if you do not have 'DB_CONNECTION' set in .env, it will automatically use mysql, and whatever config you have set up for that in the 'config/database.php' file. Hope that helps clear things up. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- cut the existing users and password migrations file and save it
  somewhere
- run a new migration for all the tables you want to create
- paste the existing file back